# $k$-local geodesics are not necessarily quasi-geodesics in flat space.

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

There is a local to global principle in hyperbolic geometry saying the following:

If $X$ is a $\delta$-hyperbolic geodesic space and $k>8\delta,$ then any $k$-local geodesic is a $\lambda, \varepsilon$ quasi-geodesic.

I am currently looking for a counterexample for non-hyperbolic space. My current idea is to consider a path in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ from $(0,0)$ to $(N,0)$ to $(N,N)$ to $(0,N).$ This path is certainly an $N$-local geodesic, but I am unsure of how to contradict it being a quasi-geodesic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider a slightly different path $$(0,0)---(2^N, 0)---(2^N, N)---(0, N)$$. That is $N$-local geodesic, has length $>2^N$ but the distance between endpoints is $N$ so it cannot be $(\lambda, c)$-quasigeodesic for $N\gg \lambda, c$. If you want you can extend it to an infinite $N$-geodesic $: ... ---(0,2N)---(2^{2N}, 2N) ---...$